# How to detect file open requests from Explorer in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, winapi, file-extension, paramstr

My Delphi Alexandria program associates certain file extensions in Registry with the Application's Exename, such that Windows shows the right icon. But I am struggling to get my program to notice a request when I double-click on a file of the correct type in Explorer. What I want is to intercept the call depending on its file extension passed through Paramcount and ParaStr(1) etc. How do I set things up in the .dpr file to

- a) notice there is a request for a filename
- b) work out whether the program is already running
- c) pass the parameters on if so, or
- d) start the program with the parameter?

d) is already OK but I don't know how to set up a)
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A) When you register a file extension in the Registry, you have to tell Windows exactly how you want your app to be called when the file extension is executed. The typical scenario is for Windows to simply run a new instance of your app with the full file path passed in as a command line parameter. As you said, you can simply use [`ParamCount()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.ParamCount)/[`ParamStr()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.ParamStr) to look for and retrieve that parameter when your app starts running.  Other choices include sending a message to a DDE server running in your app, or invoking an instance of the [`IDropTarget`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleidl/nn-oleidl-idroptarget), [`IExecuteCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-iexecutecommand), or [`IExplorerCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-iexplorercommand) interface that your app implements, etc.

B) The most common way to detect if an existing instance of your app is already running is to have it create a named kernel object, such as a Win32 [Mutex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/mutex-objects), with a persistent but unique name assigned to it. Create the object during app startup, and Windows will tell you whether the object already exists or not. If it does, then you will have to send the file path to the existing app instance and then exit immediately. Otherwise, continue running normally and process the file path as needed.

Alternatively, as you seem to already know, you can simply look for a known window in an existing instance of the app.  Which you would likely have to do anyway in order to send the file path to it.  So, you can "kill 2 birds with 1 stone", so to speak.

C) There are many [Inter-Process Communication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications) mechanisms available for sending data between processes. In this situation, using the [`WM_COPYDATA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/wm-copydata) window message is a common choice. Other choices include using named pipes, mailslots, sockets, COM, etc. Use whatever method you want.

D) You don't have to do anything extra for this.

Comment: My problem seems to be of actually noticing that Windows is requesting the program to open the file. If I double-click a known type of file and the program isn't running, it starts the program (but no action seems to occur of noticing the parameter passing). If it's running already, nothing seems to happen. I need an example of what to put before Application.Initialize in the .dpr (I think)

Comment: At last I have found out how my program refuses to start a second instance. It checks like this: 
function AppIsRunning(tool: tool_type): Boolean;
begin
  Result := FindWindow(Pchar(WSMainFormClassnames[tool]), nil) <> 0;
end;
I think it is there that I need to intercept the parameters...

Comment: Why did you write that AppIsRunning code???

Comment: @MikeScott No, that is not the right place to intercept the param. You would still need to handle the param even if your app wasn't already running. It is your responsibility to always look for the param, Windows will not tell you whether the param is present, you just have to look for it. If your app does not accept other params, simply call `ParamStr(1)` at app startup and if the returned string is not empty then use it as needed. And if Windows is running a new instance of your app, you have to find an existing instance yourself and send the param to it, Windows will not do that for you.

Comment: David Heffernan asks why I wrote that. The program is one first written and published in 1996, itself inheriting code from 1993 and before. 99% of it updated & rewritten over time of course. Short answer is that code was a way of checking which of a set of tools is running. Hard to remember when I wrote it. Why did I post it here? Perhaps I shouldn't have!